# isRotation and isSubstring method

Tags: beginner, c, strings

I have written an `isRotation` function that calls on `isSubstring` only once(I am allowed to call it only once). I have implemented my own version of isSubstring as well. Any advice is much welcome!

```
//Checks if one string is a rotation of the other
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h> 

bool isRotation(char *, char *);
bool isSubstring(char *, char *);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc == 3)
    {
        printf("%s %s a rotation of %s.\n", argv[2], isRotation(argv[1], argv[2])
            ? "is" : "is not", argv[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Incorrect number of inputs\n");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}

bool isRotation(char* s1, char* s2)
{
    size_t len1 = strlen(s1);
    size_t len2 = strlen(s2);

    if(len1 != len2 || len1 == 0 || len2 ==0)
        return 0;

    char s3[len2*2];

    bool secondCopy = false;
    int j = 0;

    /*copying 2*s2 into s3. If s2 is a rotation of s1,
      then s1 has to be found somewhere inside s3.*/
    for(size_t i = 0; i < (2*len2); i++)
    {
        s3[i] = s2[j];
        if(s2[j+1] == '\0' && secondCopy == false)
        {
            secondCopy = true;
            j = 0;
            continue;
        }
        j++;
    }

    s3[len2*2] = '\0';

    //pass the longer string to the first param
    return isSubstring(s3, s1);
}

bool isSubstring(char* s1, char* s2)
{
    //is s2 a substring of s1? 
    size_t len2 = strlen(s2);
    if(len2 == 0)
        return true;

    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while(s1[i] != '\0')
    {
        if(s2[j] == s1[i])
            j++;

        i++;            
    }

    return j == len2;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Better string copy

You are over-complicating your string duplication. There is an easier way to do it using [`memcpy`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/memcpy.html). First, simply copy the string:

```
memcpy(s3, s2, len2);
```

Then, simply copy the string again (this time, with an offset):

```
memcpy(s3 + len2, s2, len2);
```

Notice how the second copy doesn't have `-` in the last argument. With it like this, you do not have to manually copy the `null` character over afterwards as it will use the `null` character from `s2`.

Note that you can not do this as easily with `strcpy` as this function will copy the entire string, including the `null` character.

---

## Not true substring

Your `isSubstring` function doesn't actually find the substring of a string very well. Take these two strings as an example:

> ```
> abec abc
> ```

Your function would return `true` to these if these were passed in in this order. A simple fix to this would be to reset `j` to `0` every time a character is encountered that is not the right one.

```
while(s1[i] != '\0')
{
    if(s2[j] == s1[i]) {
        j++;
    } else {
        j = 0;
    }

    i++;            
}
```

---

## Misc

---

### Returning bool

> ```
> return 0;
> ```

Why are you returning a number from a `bool`-returning method?

---

### Clear up the for loop

> ```
> int j = 0;
> ...
> for(size_t i = 0; i < (2*len2); i++)
> {
>     ...
>     j++;
> }
> ```

This is somewhat confusing. You should move the `j` declaration right above the `for` loop, and move the incrementing into the signature.

---

### Refactor

The string duplication logic should be moved into an external function as to spread out the logic and make sure that every function is only doing what it needs to do and nothing else.

---

### Braces

Always use them, even around single-line statements. They make your code more maintainable and less error-prone.

---

### `While` to `for` loop

This:

> ```
> int j = 0;
> int i = 0;
> while(s1[i] != '\0')
> {
>     if(s2[j] == s1[i])
>         j++;
>
>     i++;            
> }
> ```

Can be written more cleanly as a `for` loop:

```
for(int i = 0, j = 0; s1[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    if(s2[j] == s1[i])
        j++;
}
```

Comment: Re `memcpy(s3 + (len2-1), s2, len2)` - This is incorrect. Suppose `s2` is the null-terminated string `"ab"`. The first `memcpy` copies `a` and `b` into `s3[0]` and `s3[1]`. The second call to `memcpy` copies `a` and `b` into `s3[1]` and `s3[2]`, respectively. The correct call is `memcpy(s3+len2,s2,len2)`.

Comment: Re `(-1 to ignore the null character)` -- This too is incorrect. The value returned by `strlen` does not include the terminating null character. For example, The `strlen` length of the string "ab\0" is 2, not 3.

Comment: @DavidHammen Good catch(es)! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @SirPython Hello, my professors(UCSD) have always advised us to not use brackets for one line commands inside loops and if statements. Is that not normal?

Comment: And I am a little confused on your explanation of the isSubstring method. abec and abc actually shouldn't be considered substrings should they?  because "abc" is actually not found anywhere in abec in that exact same order (coherent to how DavidHammen(the other responder) corrects my isSubstring) right?

Comment: Lastly, why do I have 2 votes to close my question? Did I post incorrectly or something? :(

Comment: @JonathanSmit You should always use braces; it is much better practice. And, what I am saying is that your `isSubstring` method - as it stands - is telling me true when I pass in abec and abc to the method itself; however, because of how your code is structured, you would never get that error in the full program because the strings cannot be of different lengths. Lastly, I don't know why you have CVs on it.

Comment: oh, i see now! thank you! and what are CVs?

Comment: @JonathanSmit CV = close votes. (sorry! ;)

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> char s3[len2*2];
> ...
> s3[len2*2] = '\0';
> ```

The above declaration is incorrect. You need to allocate one more character for the null character at the end. You are adding that null character, but you are invoking undefined behavior by not having enough space in the array for that character.

> ```
> /*copying 2*s2 into s3. If s2 is a rotation of s1,
>   then s1 has to be found somewhere inside s3.*/
> for(size_t i = 0; i < (2*len2); i++)
> {
>     s3[i] = s2[j];
>     if(s2[j+1] == '\0' && secondCopy == false)
>     {
>         secondCopy = true;
>         j = 0;
>         continue;
>     }
>     j++;
> }
> s3[len2*2] = '\0';
> ```

That's a lot of typing for what you could easily accomplish using two calls to `strcpy`:

```
strcpy(s3, s2);
strcpy(s3+len2, s2);
```

> ```
> int j = 0;
> int i = 0;
> while(s1[i] != '\0')
> {
>     if(s2[j] == s1[i])
>         j++;
>     i++;            
> }
> return j == len2;
> ```

This is just wrong. The standard approach for determining whether some string `s2` occurs within another string `s1` is to loop over the substrings of `s1` that start with the first character in `s2`, returning true if the `len2-1` characters that follow are equal to the remaining characters in `s2`, in order.

Comment: You could not use `strcpy` for this because `strcpy` copies the `null` character.

Comment: @SirPython -- Sure you can. The strings passed via `argv` are null-terminated. I would `strcpy` is the better choice than is `memcpy` because the OP is working with C-style strings.

Comment: I know that the strings from `argv` are null terminated. However, `strcpy` copies that null character too, effectively terminating the string in the middle of the allocated memory.

Comment: @SirPython - The second call to `strcpy` overwrites the null character written by the first call to `strcpy`. That extra copy of one character is a bit superfluous. Using `memcpy` would be more efficient. But I'd rather sacrifice efficiency for consistency in this case.

Comment: @SirPython - I suspect the reason you saw a problem is because you apparently thought `strlen` returns the number of characters in a string up to and including the null character.

Comment: That was definitely it. Thanks for explaining it to me!

Comment: @DavidHammen Hello, I believe my substring method does what you have explained when I ran through it line by line. Am I missing something? (Forgive me if I'm being dim-witted here! D: )

Comment: Lastly, why do I have 2 votes to close my question? Did I post incorrectly or something? :(

Comment: @JonathanSmit -- I don't have privileges at this part of the stackexchange network to see that your question has close votes, or even to issue a close vote. I can venture a guess: Your code doesn't work. This is not a site for debugging your code. You can submit lousy but basically working code for review, but you can't submit code that just doesn't work. As for your program, try running it with `abc` and `bac`. Your function indicates that `abc` is a substring of `bacbac`. It isn't.

Comment: Um, if I may, it checks for "rotation, and abc is a rotation of bac, so the output is as preferred actually. Should I add examples of input and expected output so people know it's actually giving correct results?

Comment: @JonathanSmit - No, it isn't. The rotations of `abc` are `abc`, `bca`, and `cab`. On the other hand, `cba`, `acb`, and `bac` are not rotations of `abc`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to concatenate strings. You could just "pretend" having a longer string that is `s1` concatenated twice, by adjusting the index using a simple modulo.

For example, change this:

> ```
> return isSubstring(s3, s1);
> ```

To this:

```
return isSubstring(s2, s1);
```

And the main loop in `isSubstring` can be rewritten as:

```
while(i < 2 * len2)
{
    if(s2[j] == s1[i % len2])
        j++;

    i++;            
}
```

Notice the modulo in `s1[i % len2]`. That is, when `i` reaches the end of the string, the value goes back to 0, checking again from the beginning of the string. This is practically the same as checking the index in a longer string, but without the need for a copy.

With this change, there's no more need for `s3` in `isRotation`,
so the function can be greatly simplified:

```
bool isRotation(char* s1, char* s2)
{
    size_t len1 = strlen(s1);
    size_t len2 = strlen(s2);

    if (len1 != len2 || len1 == 0 || len2 == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return isSubstring(s1, s2);
}
```

Of course, with these changes, the name of the `isSubstring` function became misleading, as now it is adapted to our special case,
and "faking" a concatenated source string. So remember to rename to something else.

Somewhat related to this,
`isSubstring` repeats some operations that were already done in the caller,
namely:

> ```
> size_t len2 = strlen(s2);
> if(len2 == 0)
>     return true;
> ```

The caller already knows the length of `s2`, so it would be good to pass that as a parameter.
And we also know that `len2 > 0`, so that check can be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

The same library that contains `strcpy()` and `strlen()` also contains `strstr()`, whose exact job is to determine if one string is contained within another.

Using the function `strstr()` will eliminate the function `isSubString()`, thereby making the code much simpler and less error-prone.

Comment: Why bother to edit trivia?  We are not in English class, trying to get a good grade on some composition paper.

Comment: I was aware of the strstr() function; however, i just wanted to practice writing an isSubstring method.

Comment: @user3629249 No, but if a post is properly formatted and contains proper grammar, then it is nicer to read and overall improves the content of this site. It also helps with first impressions from new users.